# Unescape HTML string till HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I have a HTML string which may be escaped multiple times. I want to write a function in which i pass an escaped string and it returns the unescape string. The escaped string may be escaped *n* times.

For example, my escaped string is: -

```
%253Cp%253Ebbbbbbbbb%253C/p%253E%3Cinput%20type%3D%27hidden%27%20id%3D%27grid_7_domType%27%20class%3D%27allDomObjects%27%20datatype%3D%27subpart%27%3E
```

If I unescape this string the first time then I will get:-

```
%3Cp%3Ebbbbbbbbb%3C/p%3E<input type='hidden' id='grid_7_domType' class='allDomObjects' datatype='subpart'>
```

Which is also an escaped string. So now I unescape this string again, and I get my original content:-

```
<p>bbbbbbbbb</p><input type='hidden' id='grid_7_domType' class='allDomObjects' datatype='subpart'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just continue unescaping until your string no longer contains any escape sequences, i.e. it no longer matches `/%[0-9A-F]{2}/`.

```js
var s = "%253Cp%253Ebbbbbbbbb%253C/p%253E%3Cinput%20type%3D%27hidden%27%20id%3D%27grid_7_domType%27%20class%3D%27allDomObjects%27%20datatype%3D%27subpart%27%3E";

while (s.match(/%[0-9A-F]{2}/i)) {
    s = unescape(s);
}

alert(s);
```

Probably better to use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) instead of [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) though.

Comment: Yes, But How many times we run loop? And how we recognize that we get un-escaped string?

Comment: Yes, And it's working. Is this work with n'th time escaped string? And you are still using escape, Not decodeURIComponenet. So which one is too good to use?

Comment: Yes it will work with an *n* times escaped string. I just put `unescape` because I thought that was what you were using. I would recommend using `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the help. I will use decodeURIComponent.

Comment: Not so easy... What if markup contains something like this `<code>%DEADBEEF%</code>`? You will get <code>&#x00DE;ADBEEF%</code> instead.

Comment: @c-smile I know. My original answer started by saying that it was not a 100% complete solution. I don't see a way around this issue. If you have any bright ideas, feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

For folks who want this solution in Angular 2+, there's a npm package which was born to do this.

```
npm install html-escape-unescape
```

Using this package, it's as simple as:

```
{{ someStringToBeUnescaped?times | unescape:'recursive' }}
```

It will continue to unescape the passed string until it can not be unescaped anymore and you get the HTML.
Get it [here](http://www.npmjs.com/html-escape-unescape).

Hope it helps someone.